# Asp.net webpage has expired with browser backbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble with a simple ASP.NET application and the back button after a post back.

The page in question has a simple form on it, some text fields etc, and a dropdown that does a postback (autopostback).

The "normal" flow is the user fills out the form and perhaps changes the dropdown. Based on the dropdown value the page content might change.

The problem I'm having is that after the user has changed the dropdown and the postback has completed then the user submit button, page is navigating to other page and then when I click the back button. They see a "webpage has expired" message from IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're asking the browser to 'go back' to a state before the form was submitted. The page has 'expired' in this case because the information on the form has already been sent to the server.

You're getting post-backs in places you might not realize. For example, "Based on the drop-down value the page content might change." You're likely accomplishing this thru an OnChange event which triggers a post-back when the drop-down changes. Now the back button will behave as you've discovered.

You have a couple of choices:

1. Do your form-content changing client-side in Javascript.
2. Rebuild your form with with AJAX/UpdatePanels and partial-postbacks.
3. Put links on your page to commonly-accessed parts of your app and hope folks use those instead of back. :)

Comment: Thank you, I added update panel and working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behaviour in browsers. When you post data and then goes back, browsers will tell you that the content is expired. Imagine you have just bought something, then you don't want the browser to resend that info. The solution is to use Ajax to post to your server, then the browser doesn't update the page and won't show you the warning.